# Google Groups specify account in URL

Tags: google-groups

I have two Google accounts and signed in to both of them. For example to access gmail for one account URL is https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0, for an other inbox it is https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1. Is there anything like this for Google Groups? Or maybe there is a way to set default account for this product. Each time I open Google Groups website I am logging in as first user and switching to the second is not saved.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Google Groups doesn't have a similar feature. As an alternative set a profile for each account in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think now they added this feature, but it still doesn't work. I have multiple accounts, but personalized URL always directs me to my first account Google groups.

[image: admin settings for Custom URLs]